# kafka and parallel consumer: why order is important into a microservice architecture

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, kafka-consumer-api

I started to dive into kafka ecosystem.

I was surprised to find out that by default, each consumer only digests one "event" at a time, sequentially!

It's given by offset acknowledgement, unit of parallelism is at partition-level and some other stuff... you can find nice details [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-confluent-parallel-message-processing-client/).

If I need to consume received messages in parallel into my application node thread pool, I need to use and make some non-default development effort to get it.

By other hand, several technologies have their own recipes to get it: [quarkus/smallrye](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.13/advanced/blocking.html), confluentinc has a [parallel-consummer](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer), spring, ...

I hope to find an by-default code configuration in order to get it.

This suggests me that perhaps, some other technologies are more suitable in order to **consume messages** straightforwardly...

- Why **parallel consumer** is not given by default into libraries?
- Why order is important into a microservice architecture?

Answer (score 1):

`KafkaConsumer` is a relatively low-level object, that's basically capable of reading records from given offset position, seeking to a particular offset, reading and saving that offset in existing Kafka store (called `__consumer_offsets`). Similarly, the receive API is fully synchronous with its `poll(Duration)` signature.

If more custom, e.g. asynchronous behaviour is desired, then you can use the wrappers like parallel-consumer or spring-kafka.

When it comes to library design, very often it is preferable to do only one thing (basically an applied single responsibility principle).

As an example, consider that if the "main" library were to be asynchrous, the library providers would need to provide thread creation and maintaining semantics, what happens when there are no records (compare to spring-kafka's listeners), and so on. By exposing low-level API these concerns that are not immediately relevant to Kafka these concerns can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

> Why parallel consumer is not given by default into libraries?

Kafka *clients* are a largely pluggable ecosystem. The core developers are focused on optimizing the server code, and the built-in client libraries (and serializers) work "well-enough" <sup>(TM)</sup>. So, therefore, a "by default code configuration" for parallel-consumption doesn't exist.

> Why order is important into a microservice architecture

That completely depends on your app, but one example is payment-processing or handling any sort of ledger system (after all, Kafka is a sort of distributed ledger). You cannot withdraw money without first depositing a balance. This is not unique to microservices.

Comment: Are you aggre with latest answer provided by Panagiotis Bougioukos?

Comment: Consumer groups depend on multiple instances to scale, yes... And as the other answer says, higher level frameworks like Spring already have `concurrency` properties for spawning multiple threads in the same application. Kafka Streams also supports multiple threads per app.